# Saved Images take a while to appear in gallery

Tags: android

So in my app I am saving a photo and it then appears in the gallery of the phone. I think it appears pretty quickly, but it is not instant and I am getting bad reviews because of it. I have seen apps where they appear instantly in the gallery and I want mine to do the same to avoid more bad reviews. I am using `sendBroadcast` which I thought was the quickest way to do it, but I guess I am wrong.

```
 public File savePhoto(File pic,String ext)
{
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Pics");



    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists())
    {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) return null;
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile=null;

    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + "."+ext);
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Pics"))));

    Toast.makeText(this, "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return mediaFile;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong here. `sendBroadcast()` with `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED` is very taxing and could be causing the delay in question.

You can try using the following in its place:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(mediaFile)));
```

I am using `mediaFile` that you create just above your `sendBroadcast()` method. This should be better, since you are focusing on just one file.